# Where can I find alternative greeters for LightDM?

Tags: lightdm

Is there a place where I could find a list of LightDM greeters and where I could download them?
I would very much like to see some custom made greeters so I can fully customise my Ubuntu :)
I know that one of the lead designers in Ubuntu once showed an animation with imps in the greeter, now that was amazing but I want something different.

Comment: The Arch Wiki lists a few greeters: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM#Greeter - the links are to the AUR, but you can use the PKGBUILD of each package to see where it originates from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LightDM) contains a reasonably accurate list of available greeters. In Ubuntu the following greeters are in the archive (package name in brackets):

- Unity Greeter (unity-greeter)
- GTK+ Greeter (lightdm-gtk-greeter)
- KDE Greeter (lightdm-kde-greeter)
- WebKit Greeter (lightdm-webkit-greeter)
- RazorQt Greeter (razorqt-lightdm-greeter)